# Is there a method for identifying if an equation can be rearranged into a linear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm re-asking a question which was unclear in its original post.

I am trying to debug a piece of software that solves linear equations given user input.  For reasons, the user input may not be restricted to only linear equations. Therefore the set of equations must first be analysed to determine if the equations provided can be used in a linear algebra solver.

Given the system of equations:

```
3*x+5*y=0
x-3*y=0
```

It is trivial to determine if the system is linear and then solve using row reduction.

However, given the system:

```
3*x+5*y=0
x/y=3
```

The equality `x-3*y=0`is equivalent to `x/y=3 (y!=0)` yet only the former can be easily determined to be solved using linear algebra methods.

I am not sure if/how to determine if the second equality can be rearranged to be linear.  This is a problem because the system is fully defined, however linear algebra can't be implemented to solve.

Is there a good method for identifying if an equation can be rearranged into a linear form?

Comment: Intuitively I think some second derivates should be zero.

Comment: They are in fact not equivalent...

Comment: For x/y=3 the second derivates are not all 0

Comment: To reiterate @user251257 point, what do you mean by "equivalence"? Is it that the solution set of one equals the solution set to the other?

Comment: I mean one is a rearrangement of the other... And I will edit to note y!=0.

Comment: While I appreciate the high specificity of this forum, I am using the word 'equivalent' as I understand it.  Perhaps there is a better language for what I mean.

Comment: I doubt there is an algorithm to determine whether the set of solutions is a (affine) space.